# how to make a box plot with several conditions

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having a hardtime figuring this out, my data looks like this

```
df<-structure(list(X = c("Condition1_r1", "Condition1_r2", "Condition1_r3", 
"Condition2_r1", "Condition2_r2", "Condition2_r3", "Condition3_r1", 
"Condition3_r2", "Condition3_r3", "Condition4_r1", "Condition4_r2", 
"Condition4_r3"), Start_0.05 = c(1985690L, 1648182L, 1753785L, 
1503562L, 1766865L, 1668165L, 1667551L, 1696531L, 1641864L, 1948220L, 
1746022L, 1684197L), X24h_0.05 = c(1806206L, 1808040L, 1891484L, 
1625457L, 1941141L, 1861851L, 1779449L, 1868057L, 1826050L, 1937257L, 
1904913L, 1860859L), Start_0.1 = c(1730114L, 1725849L, 1789878L, 
1740597L, 1701077L, 1713350L, 1707332L, 1783543L, 1797749L, 1610270L, 
2044620L, 1841091L), X24h_0.1 = c(1834778L, 1869877L, 1937330L, 
1888427L, 1886134L, 1902281L, 1835693L, 1937490L, 1933643L, 1716316L, 
1953273L, 1942712L), Start_0.5 = c(1755666L, 1668527L, 1695593L, 
1751354L, 1720210L, 1657771L, 2257244L, 1686353L, 1645991L, 1782086L, 
1785223L, 1793709L), X24h_0.5 = c(1865112L, 1830708L, 1863313L, 
1901987L, 1901676L, 1857649L, 2012898L, 1849991L, 1827155L, 1858165L, 
1930146L, 1958237L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

I have four conditions and each conditions has three replicates
then I have two subconditions (which one is start and one is 24h at various time lag.

what I do to plot is as follows

```
xx2 <- melt(df, id.vars = "X")
ggplot(xx2, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

but it does not reflect on my groups, any thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by @Axeman in his comment your `variable` contains multiple pieces of information. Hence, as a first step I would suggest to make your data tidy by splitting `variable` into the subcondition or `group` and the `replicate` which could be achieved in one go by using `tidy::pivot_longer` instead of `melt`. Afterwards you could map the the subcondition or `group` on `x` and the `replicate` on e.g. `fill`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

xx2 <- pivot_longer(df, -X,
  names_to = c("group", "replicate"),
  names_sep = "_"
)

ggplot(
  xx2,
  aes(x = group, y = value, fill = replicate)
) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `facet_wrap`:

```
ggplot(xx2, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + 
    geom_boxplot() +
    facet_wrap(~X)
```

Comment: no this creates 100 images as well as it is not giving boxplot

Comment: Those are boxplots, just not visible due to the y-axis range. Explain what kind of output you expect.

Comment: @Ludwig, have you looked at X? It is unique for each row. Both `X` and `variable` are actually encoding multiple things.

Comment: @Axeman You are right. In this case they aren't boxplots. Still, it would be great to know what OP expected.

Comment: @nik id you mean something like this? `ggplot(xx2, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + geom_jitter(aes(col = X), width = 0.1, height = 0)`